# syncing feature files and step definition after change

Tags: specflow, azure-devops, speclog

Given a feature file I can generate step definitions in visual studio no problem. Are there any tools (e.g. visual studio plugins?) out there, which allow me to sync feature files and step definitions (just the step definition method signatures of course)?

We are also using speclog which is synced with tfs. Are there ways to synch tfs and speclog in terms of feature files (i.e. the original acceptance criteria in speclog)?

Comment: I'm not sure exactly what you are asking here. what exactly do you mean by 'sync feature files and step definitions'? Do you mean generate all of the step definitions for all features and place them in a step file automatically?

Comment: No, as i said, I know how to do this. GIVEN a feature file WHEN I change the when part of a feature file THEN I would like this to be automatically reflected in the step's signature

Answer (score 1):

There's currently no support to update the step definition signature automatically. I guess what you're looking for is some kind of Gherkin/step definition refactoring tools.

One thing that might be useful though for what you want to accomplish is the step definition report, that lists unused/unbound steps: http://www.specflow.org/documentation/Reporting/

For syncing feature files from source control (e.g. TFSVC or Git) to SpecLog, you can link requirements to feature files like outlined here: https://github.com/techtalk/SpecLog-Resources/wiki/Gherkin-Attachments-For-Acceptance-Criteria